# One case statement for multiple parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

Below is my sample code situation

```
declare @Ka int = select count(empid) from employee where age between 18 and 22
declare @Kb int = select count(empid) from employee where age between 23 and 30
declare @Kc int = select count(empid) from employee where age between 31 and 35
```

Now, If Ka/Kb/Kc has some value other than 0 or null then it should display 'x' and if not it should display blank. So my select statement is:

```
select  
   CASE WHEN @Ka = 0 then ''  
        ELSE 'X' 
        END AS 'Ka',
   CASE WHEN @Kb = 0 then ''  
        ELSE 'X' 
        END AS 'Kb',
   CASE WHEN @Kc = 0 then ''  
        ELSE 'X' 
        END AS 'Kc'
```

So If I have around more parameters, should I do a case statement for each parameter as above? Is there a way to do single case statement including all the parameters obeying the condition? Or is there a simple way to accomplish something similar to this?

Comment: Note that your variables, here, could never have a value of *`NULL`*. Doing a `COUNT` on a table will always return a value, even if it contains no rows. This isn't, however, how other aggregate functions work (`COUNT(*)` of a resultset of 0 rows would return 0, however, `SUM(Column)` of a result set of 0 rows would not return a result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do it this way? It seems much more efficient if you were to do the following (without variables):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 22 THEN empid END) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS Ka,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 23 AND 30 THEN empid END) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS Kb,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 35 THEN empid END) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS Kc
FROM Employee;
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  Don't do this.  You need the logic *inside* the query:

```
select sum(case when age between 18 and 22 then 1 else 0 end) as age_18_22,
       sum(case when age between 23 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as age_23_30,
       sum(case when age between 31 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as age_31_35       
from employee e;
```

SQL doesn't work by substituting text in query strings.  I mean, you can do that -- it is called *dynamic sql*.  But you should first learn the basics of expressing queries.

Comment: For this case, I think OP really want `'x'` or `blank` as final result

Comment: Understood.What is the difference involved? Any performance difference between my older way and the suggested way?

Comment: @Jiah The biggest benefit is you are parsing the table once, and doing your calculations as your parse it. With your SQL, the table had to be parsed once for each variable, and then you had to then do further checks on the variable values.

Comment: @Larnu If I get a case where I want to add Ka+Kb+Kc then I have to go for parameter right?

Comment: @Jiah, no. I'd recommend the use of a CTE at that stage.